# Практическая разница и смысл между обычной строкой и байтовой?

Tags: python, строки

Подскажите новичку, желательно переводя с технического на русский:

Любая информация это двоичный код и только так хранится информация в памяти. В чём практический смысл существования байтовой строки в питоне? Вся информация итак байтовая, вопрос лишь в том, каким образом к ней подходить. Информация всё равно транслируется из двоичного кода, например, в шестнадцатиричные символы, в символы ASCII - например представление байтовой строки b'Hello World'

Точно также, двоичный код транслируется в обычную строку. Зачем это разделение?

Comment: "Вся информация и так байтовая", но вы обычно не можете с ней удобно работать напрямую как с наборами байтов. А с байтовой строкой - можете. По идее для этого она и нужна - для удобства работы с ней.

Comment: Затем что символ (буква) - это довольно абстрактная сущность, которую можно представить представить в байтах кучей разных способов (в разных кодировках). Обычные строки - для универсального хранения символов, независимо от конкретного их реального представления в памяти. Байтовые строки могут быть использованы для хранения текста в конкретной кодировке, например - для сохранения в файл или для передачи куда-то. Т.е. обычные строки - это слой абстракции над фактическим байтовым представлением строк, это позволяет упростить работу с текстом, отделить обработку текста от технических деталей.

Answer (score 6):

Аналогия: обычная строка — это устная речь, байтовая строка — это звуки. Запись звуков будет звучать всегда и для всех одинаково. Но смысл этих звуков будет зависеть от языка. Например, мы не сможем правильно интерпретировать последовательность звуков [лист] или [гифт], если не знаем, какой язык применить для "расшифровки" в смысл.

Так и с байтами. Если в файле записаны байты `11000000`, то мы никак не узнаем, что именно записано в этой файле, пока не станет известно, какой это "язык". Это может быть буква "А" в кодировке Windows-1251, это может быть буква "ю" в кодировке KOI8-R, и это может быть просто число 192 в байтах.

А если мы захотим записать число 192 в файл в виде текста, т.е. как три символа `1`, `9` и `2`, то в файле уже окажется `001100010011100100110010` (если мы будем использовать 8-битную кодировку ASCII или какую-нибудь другую, которая базируется на ней).

Answer (score 5):

> Зачем это разделение?

Это не разделение. **Символы** (буквы, цифры, скобки, ...) и **байты** — это просто **2 различные существа**.

Лучше всего представить себе, что они настолько различные существа, *что у них нет ничего общего и что между ними нет никаких связей* — чтобы лучше понят разницу и преодолеть ложное представление, вытекающие из того, что:

> Когда-то — очень давно — символы и байты были почти то же самое, буквы были только английские и кодировка «один символ, один байт».

1. **Символы** — это **текстовые единицы**, как буквы, цифры, запятая, точка, и т.д.
   Они для нас, **людей**.
   (Вообще не нужно знать, в каком виде их Питон сохраняет. Я знал, **удивился** и забыл.)

   Даже начинающий программист не имеет с этим проблем. Например, он хочет записать знакомую фразу «Hello, world!», но не на английском, т.e. не

   ```
   print('Hello, world!')
   ```

   а на своем родном — по-русски, по-китайски или по-японски.

   Просто наберет на своей национальной клавиатуре буквы для перевода этой фразы в свой родной язык, и все будет работать как часы:

   ```
   print('Привет, мир!')
   ```
2. **Байты** — это **последовательности из (в общем) 8 битов**.
   (Каждый бит может быть только нулей или единицей.) Пример байта: `01001101`.
   Значение байта можно также выразить как целое число в диапазоне **0 — 255**

   Они для **машин**.

   Нам их нужно применить только в специальных случаях, прежде всего для **обмена информациями** между машинами и/или между программами.

Как я уже написал, представите себе, что у символов и байтов нет ничего общего.
Как другой пример вы можете себе представить разницу между английским алфавитом и азбукой:

```
abcdefghijklmnоp...
абвгдеёжзийклмно...
```

Кажется, что что-то у них сходное, что-то подобное, но даже сходные буквы читаются по-разному.

Подобным образом, кажется, что «обычные» и байтовые строки почти то же самое:

```
print('Hello, world!')
```

> Hello, world!

```
print(b'Hello, world!')
```

> b'Hello, world!'

Но совпадение здесь только случайно, потому что в байтовых строках возможно отдельные байты задавать как ASCII символы (и Питон их тоже так соображает), но только когда они из диапазона **32 — 127**.

Следующие примеры уже так гладко не работают:

```
print('Привет, мир!')
```

> Привет, мир!

```
print(b'Привет, мир!')
```

> SyntaxError: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters.

```
print('C:\User')
```

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

```
print(b'C:\User')
```

> b'C:\\User'